# select where time = x or later

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns `username` and `timestamp` . When a username is entered the current timestamp is as well.

I would like to fetch the rows of all the new users from a certain time until now, but the start time varies. Lets make it a timestamp represented by x.

I would like to use SQL to select all rows in a table which have a time-stamp in the time range of timestamp x up until `now()`.

Comment: why don't you write the query for yourself? You have clearly mentioned what you need.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do this. I tried do so SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE (timestamp > '$time') but this did not return anything.

Comment: You need to pass the time in a format that MySQL understands.

Comment: What exact value is `$time`?  Print it out - it may be blank, null, now, a future date or the wrong format for mysql

Comment: @Bohemian it is a MySQL timestamp

Comment: If it's MySQL you can use NOW() to call the current date/time; for SQL it's GETDATE().  There's no NOW() in SQL.

Comment: Just a note on SQL injection.  If you're passing `$time` into the query as a variable, you should use a parameterised query, or at least make sure it's a valid timestamp before injecting it into the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tablename where timestamp between cast(x as timestamp) and now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the statement you had placed in the comments but without the quotes. `SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE timestamp > x`

And for X you would enter time in 24hr format ie. 15:26